# How can I have a copy of this old paper by Frobenius?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

How can I have a copy of this old paper and a translation of it?

Frobenius, G. (1902). Uber primitive Gruppen des Grades n und der Klasse n - 1. S. B. Akad. Berlin 1902, 455-459.

Comment: Interlibrary loan?

Comment: Also asked (and closed) on m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985372/how-can-i-have-a-copy-of-this-old-paper

Comment: "and a translation of it" is probably asking a lot for papers of that vintage (or even more recent) in German.

Comment: Are you aware that the papers of Frobenius were gathered into his *Collected Works* in the late 1960s? It won't help with a translation, of course, but it means you can find all his papers bound together in these volumes in many university libraries.

Answer (score 20):

It is freely available online. You can find it here:

http://goo.gl/pDkRi6

(Download the file and take a look at pages 455-459 of it.)

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me how you found it?

Comment: Google "Sitzungsberichte der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin". The first result you'll get is some type of online repository of the journal.